# Syntax error at or near ":" postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I would like to drop a role that contains this name:

```
http://bphppgadmin.kattare.com/phppgadmin/vagrant
```

I perform query from terminal and Postgresql throws syntax error.

### Error:

```
DROP ROLE http://bphppgadmin.kattare.com/phppgadmin/vagrant;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: DROP ROLE http://bphppgadmin.kattare.com/phppgadmin/vagrant;
```

Anyone knows how to escape colon? I tried several solution however no luck so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identifiers with non-standard characters need to be enclosed in double quotes:

```
DROP ROLE "http://bphppgadmin.kattare.com/phppgadmin/vagrant";
```

More details in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: That is the perfect answer. Thanks :)